# Android USB mode without usb cable

Tags: android, usb

It is known that we can choose "USB connection type" when we connect an android phone to pc with a USB cable. My question is:

1. Can I enable the "USB connection type" selection UI without USB cable? such as in my program.
2. What does Android OS do when a phone is connected to pc by a USB cable? for example, load any drivers.

Hope anyone could me some suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **USB connection type** UI will not be present in all phones

Comment: As nandeesh pointed out, the "USB connection type" is NOT part of standard Android. It is one of the several OEM customsations. @john why do you need to launch that screen? What is it that you intend to do?...

Comment: Bascially, I want to switch the working modes without usb cable, such as switch from "mass storage" to OEM specific "sync".

Comment: More detailed, I want to know the OS workflow when a usb cable is connected between android phone and pc, and then redo this workflow without cable in my code

Comment: Doing apps that mimic the OS... hm, that's not sounds good.

Comment: Probably not just app, if OS or driver revision is required, we may do that part too.